# How to change focus color for textfield in kotlin?

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

I am not able to change the focus color for edittext

Tried using custom edittext, but the colour remain red.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To change the focus color for a TextField in Kotlin, you can set the focusedIndicatorColor property. Here's an example:

```
   <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
android:id="@+id/myTextFieldLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:hint="My TextField"
app:focusedIndicatorColor="@color/my_focus_color">
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    android:id="@+id/myTextField"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

In the above code, we set the focusedIndicatorColor property of the TextInputLayout to a custom color defined in the my_focus_color resource.

Alternatively, you can also set this property programmatically in Kotlin code:

```
val myTextFieldLayout = findViewById<TextInputLayout>(R.id.myTextFieldLayout)
```

myTextFieldLayout.setBoxStrokeColorResource(R.color.my_focus_color)

In the above code, we use the setBoxStrokeColorResource() method to set the focus color to my_focus_color.

Note that the focusedIndicatorColor property was added in Material Components version 1.1.0. If you are using an older version, you can use the setBoxStrokeColor() method instead.